# how to create dynamic string in php like sample?

Tags: php, laravel

hi i want to create string in laravel with foreach and that string must be like this sample:

```
'item1,item2,item3'
```

**Pay attention to commas and quotation marks.**

anyone can help me?

Comment: Question is not clear enough to me at least. How many items? Is it always 'item' or is that also variable?

Comment: The Question is not Clear, Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `implode` function.

Have a look at https://www.php.net/implode

It does exactly that with arrays.

example:

```
$string = implode(",", $array);
```

Comment: How do you know OP has an array?

Comment: from the mentioning of `foreach`!

Comment: Not sure how important the *with foreach* part of the question is.

Comment: its work thank you